# Finding which method is causing a NPE in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, nullpointerexception

I have an object that has a set of methods called on it like:

```
objectName.method1().method2().method3();
```

and I want to know which one of those methods is causing the *NullPointerException* to be thrown. Is there a way to do this in the **Eclipse debugger**?

Comment: You are invoking method2() on what is returned by method1(), the same for method3(). Unless these are really well tested and used classes like from the idk itself, I would follow the advice in the answer. You have 3 different objects and 3 different methods. An stack trace mess

Comment: Each `.` and `[` are potential causes for null pointer exceptions.  To avoid the situation you have, have at most one of these on a single line.

Comment: I can't imagine reading the stack trace would be terribly difficult.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which specific value was unexpectedly `null` (e.g `objectName` or return value from `method1()` or `method2()`), then I recommend splitting this logic into multiple lines.  Then, you'll be able to set specific breakpoints in the debugger and step to the exact failing line of code.

This has benefits when running in production too.  If it happens after you deploy or in a live customer environment, then you'll get a more specific line number in the stack trace that points to the exact line of code with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some careful stepping in Eclipse debugger. Put a breakpoint on the line you are describing. If you have local variables available in bytecode, then you will immediately know it the first call causes problems by looking at a value of `objectName`. If it is null, you know that it is the first call.

If not, step into the method (F5). This will bring you to the implementation of first method. Then you can immediately return from it by stepping out (step return - F7). You should be back at the orignal line with debugger ready to step through the next method. You continue by stepping into again (F5). That should take you to the implementation of the next method. If you arrived there, then there is still no exception. Step return (F7) again.

Continue until you get to some exception handler instead of the method you wanted to step into. This is the one you are after, or perhaps the one before it, because that one returned null.

You can also play with "Run to line" function (default Ctrl + R) to do that a bit more easily.